# How to implement grouped chart of stacked chart and bar chart using d3js v4

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

I want to implement a grouped chart, which will have stacked chart and a bar chart.

I am new to d3.js charts and little confused about the approach to build mixed kind of chart.

I have tried to built a stacked chart and painted bar chart, here I have some doubts that these two charts are not grouped very well.

Please find my approach in the below fiddle.

[`Demo Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/0mdmb7tv/1/)