# d3js - How to move x- domain values towards right

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

I am working on one chart using d3.js version 4.
So I want to move plotting of bar chart towards right as shown below. 
[image]

Usually the bar renders from starting position as shown below
[image]

Please help ....! 
    [`Demo fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/L7kjbrfo/)

Comment: Please share some code so that we can help you out. Preferred jsfiddle

Comment: @Shiladitya Please find the working code here https://jsfiddle.net/L7kjbrfo/

Comment: fiddle example looks fine, it's not reflecting the problem what you have stated.

Comment: @Shiladitya Hey.... Yes there is no problem with chart, but I want it like first image... with some gap left over at the starting marked as red line

Answer (score 1):

In D3 v4.x there is no native method to set the absolute amount of padding before the first tick in a band scale.

There are several *hacks*, though, if you accept a hacky solution.

One of those hacky solutions consists in simply adding fake values before the real domain...

```
xScale.domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"].concat(stackedData[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.data.day;
})));
```

... and showing only the real domain in the axis:

```
xAxis.scale(xScale)
    .tickValues(stackedData[0].map(function(d) {
        return d.data.day;
    }));
```

Here is the result:

```js
var self = this;
self.plannedHours = 80;
self.averagePlannedHours = 70;
self.averagPlannedItems = 7;
self.isStoryPoints = false;
self.availableHours = 0;
self.data = [{
  "day": "Mon",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 80,
  "doneWork": 0
}, {
  "day": "Tue",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 80,
  "doneWork": 30
}, {
  "day": "Wed",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 90,
  "doneWork": 35
}, {
  "day": "Thu",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 90,
  "doneWork": 50
}, {
  "day": "Fri",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 90,
  "doneWork": 55
}, {
  "day": "Sat",
  "avgPlannedHours": 0,
  "overPlannedHours": 0,
  "doneWork": 0
}, {
  "day": "Sun",
  "avgPlannedHours": 0,
  "overPlannedHours": 0,
  "doneWork": 0
}, {
  "day": "Mon1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 80,
  "doneWork": 0
}, {
  "day": "Tue1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 80,
  "doneWork": 30
}, {
  "day": "Wed1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 90,
  "doneWork": 35
}, {
  "day": "Thu1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 90,
  "doneWork": 50
}, {
  "day": "Fri1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 70,
  "overPlannedHours": 90,
  "doneWork": 55
}, {
  "day": "Sat1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 0,
  "overPlannedHours": 0,
  "doneWork": 0
}, {
  "day": "Sun1",
  "avgPlannedHours": 0,
  "overPlannedHours": 0,
  "doneWork": 0
}];
self.dataCopy = self.data.slice();
self.normalisedData = [];
normalizeData();

function normalizeData() {
  self.normalisedData = self.data.map(function(data, index) {
    if (self.plannedHours > self.averagePlannedHours) {
      data.overPlannedHours = data.overPlannedHours - data.avgPlannedHours;
    } else if (self.plannedHours < self.averagePlannedHours) {
      data.avgPlannedHours = data.avgPlannedHours - data.overPlannedHours;
    }
    return data;
  });
}

renderChart();

function renderChart() {

  var colors1 = ['#FFD692', '#A9EEFF'],
    avgPlannedHoursLineColor = "#36CFF5",
    plannedHoursLineColor = self.plannedHours > self.averagePlannedHours ? "#F5A623" : "#A8EEFF",
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(colors1),
    margin = {
      top: 25,
      right: 180,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
    },
    svg = d3.select("#chart-container"),
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // var stackedData = d3.layout.stack()(self.normalisedData);
  var stack = d3.stack().keys(["avgPlannedHours", "overPlannedHours"]);
  var stackedData = stack(self.normalisedData);
  stackedData[1] = stackedData[1].map(function(stData, index) {
    stData[0] = 0;
    return stData;
  });

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom();
  if (self.plannedHours > self.averagePlannedHours) {
    var swappedStack = stackedData[0];
    stackedData[0] = stackedData[1];
    stackedData[1] = swappedStack;
  }

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.4)
    .align(0.3);

  xScale.domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"].concat(stackedData[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.data.day;
  })));

  var x1Scale = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.6);

  x1Scale.domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"].concat(stackedData[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.data.day;
  })));

  xAxis.scale(xScale)
    .tickValues(stackedData[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.data.day;
    }));

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);
  if (self.plannedHours > self.averagePlannedHours) {
    yScale.domain([0,
      d3.max(stackedData[0],
        function(d) {
          return d[0] + d[1];
        })
    ]).nice();
  } else {
    yScale.domain([0,
      d3.max(stackedData[stackedData.length - 1],
        function(d) {
          return d[0] + d[1];
        })
    ]).nice();
  }

  yAxis.scale(yScale)
    .ticks(10);


  var layer = g.selectAll(".stack")
    .data(stackedData)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "stack")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    });

  layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.data.day);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1] + d[0]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1] + d[0]);
    })
    .attr("width", 24);

  var workDoneLayer = g.selectAll(".work-done")
    .data(self.dataCopy)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "work-done")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x1Scale(d.day);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.doneWork);
    })
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - yScale(d.doneWork);
    });

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  var averagLineData = self.dataCopy[0].avgPlannedHours;
  var plannedHoursDotted = d3.max(self.dataCopy, function(d) {
    return d.overPlannedHours;
  });
  g.append("svg:line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", yScale(averagLineData))
    .attr("y2", yScale(averagLineData))
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", ("5, 5"))
    .style("stroke", avgPlannedHoursLineColor);
  g.append("svg:line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", yScale(plannedHoursDotted))
    .attr("y2", yScale(plannedHoursDotted))
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", ("5, 5"))
    .style("stroke", plannedHoursLineColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart-container" width="750" height="251"> </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and it is nice to have this hacky way. I have another doubt.  If you look at my fiddle, I was trying to group stacked chart and bar chart but I could not able to do it. if you can how can we group them so that the chart will scale up properly for more no of domain values. Here is the link for that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977119/how-to-implement-grouped-chart-of-stacked-chart-and-bar-chart-using-d3js-v4

Answer (score -1):

Consider your svg like an HTML element. You inside, bar are grouped by a "d" element. You just have to add a `transform: translateX(50px)` to move the whole bar to the right.

For example, just add this css rule on your document to align the black, blue, an yellow bar :

```
g.stack {
    transform: translateX(48px);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to do this way and realised that this approach is not right, because the bars painted inside svg in g tag is sibling to x-axis g tag. So If I move g tags of bars then the tick marks will not shown properly and which will break for huge number of domain values on x-axis.